# wrapping pictures with box

Tags: includegraphics, fbox

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\graphicspath{ {d:/pics/} }
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\fbox{\centerline{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-a}}}
\caption{Picture 1}
\vspace{1in}
\shadowbox{\centerline{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-a}}}
\caption{Picture 2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I'm trying to wrap the picture with a box. I want to know how to change the size of the box itself.

Comment: \fboxsep is the distance from the contents to the frame.  \fboxrule is the line thickness used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello and welcome to Tex.
For the first one I would just recommend `framebox(){}`.
For the shadowbox just delete the `\centerline` and add \centering right after `\begin{figure}`.
see code below. is that what you wanted?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\graphicspath{ {d:/pics/} }
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
\framebox(90,70){{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-a}}}
\caption{Picture 1}
\vspace{1in}
\shadowbox{{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-a}}}
\caption{Picture 2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what i want thanks!